# Conditional rendering in Flutter displaying wrong Widget for a moment, but then correct it

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am having a weird bug. I am trying to display a widget conditionally, using the value of my Provider. The problem is that it displays the incorrect widget for a second, and then corrects it. It is really annoying.

This is what I'm trying to display:

```
(context.watch<Tasks>().tasks.isEmpty
                    ? const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'No tasks',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Tasks",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),
                            ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: context.watch<Tasks>().tasks.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                final Task task = tasks[index];
                                return TaskWidget(task: task);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
```

And here is my provider:

```
class Tasks with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [];

  Tasks() {
    initialState();
  }

  List get tasks => _tasks;

  void initialState() {
    syncDataWithProvider();
  }

  void add(Task task) {
    _tasks.add(task);
    updateSharedPreferences();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void delete(Task task) {
    _tasks.removeWhere((element) => element.title == task.title);
    updateSharedPreferences();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteAll() {
    _tasks.clear();
    updateSharedPreferences();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void edit(String? taskTitle, String newTaskTitle) {
    List<Task> newTasks = [];

    for (final task in _tasks) {
      if (task.title == taskTitle) {
        task.title = newTaskTitle;
      }
      newTasks.add(task);
    }

    _tasks = newTasks;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getTaskLength() {
    return _tasks.length;
  }

  Future updateSharedPreferences() async {
    List<String> myTasks =
        _tasks.map((task) => json.encode(task.toJson())).toList();

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await prefs.setStringList('tasks', myTasks);
  }

  Future syncDataWithProvider() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var result = prefs.getStringList('tasks');

    if (result != null) {
      _tasks = result.map((task) => Task.fromJson(json.decode(task))).toList();
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

If it is needed, here is my [complete code](https://github.com/enricocaliolo/todo-app-flutter). Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: can you provide any GIF image when you get the wrong widget?

Comment: did you mean that, your UI display `No Task`  for a moment, then show the correct widget ?

Comment: Yes. I recorded a [gif](https://streamable.com/y3nqna), which shows exactly what is happening.

Comment: sorry, i can't open the link.
but, my suggestion is, make your future function is lazy load to render the UI.

Comment: sorry, I didn't follow. Should I turn my syncDataWithProvider() function a lazy load? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> turn my syncDataWithProvider() function a lazy load? How would I do
> that?

the aswer is with:  `notifyListeners()`. use it like `setState` in `Statefullwidget`

```
 class Tasks with ChangeNotifier {
   bool _isLoading = false;
   bool get isLoading => isLoading;
   
   ....

   Future syncDataWithProvider() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    // then call notifylistener. to tell the UI that 
    // some value has been changed.
    
    notifyListeners(); // =>: hey UI new value from Provider,
    
   // then execute your future function 
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var result = prefs.getStringList('tasks');

    if (result != null) {
      _tasks = result.map((task) => Task.fromJson(json.decode(task))).toList();
    }

    // when its done, update the loading state to false again.
    // then notify the UI that, new data has been fetched and loading is done
    _isLoading = false;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

now you can use it like below:

```
context.watch<Tasks>().isLoading 
   ? Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()) // show loader while fetch data
   : (context.watch<Tasks>().tasks.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text('No tasks',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                   )
            : Expanded(
              ......
```

this is not best practice, but it should be work.